# How to install wine32 on Ubuntu 20.04 when I can't overcome missing dependency issues

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I'm trying to install wine32 as it is required by PlayOnLinux. The installation fails due to missing dependencies.

This is not a duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), specifically I have already tried the things suggested there such as:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Checking all sources are enabled in: gksu software-properties-gtk.
Changing the server.

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

returns 0 everywhere including "not upgraded"

Requested output linked question:

```
$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done   
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list     
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted    
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted 
#Added by software-properties
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to   
# newer versions of the distribution.   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted  
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse universe #Added by software-properties    
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the    
## distribution.    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse main restricted universe #Added by software-properties    
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu     
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any   
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.     
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe     
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe     
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe 
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu     
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to     
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in      
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu    
## security team.   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse   
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse     
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse   
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested 
as  
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes  
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.   
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review     
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted
 universe multiverse    
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
#Added by software-properties   
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.    
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the     
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.     
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse main restricted universe 
#Added by software-properties   
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe     
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse  
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# This system was installed using small removable media     
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"   
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.     
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,   
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*     
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal main   
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal main   
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main     
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main     
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader/ubuntu focal main   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/helkaluin/webp-pixbuf-loader/ubuntu focal main   
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu focal main   
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu focal main   
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main     
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/ stable main     
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal main   
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu foca main  
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal main   
deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_20.04/
deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_20.04/
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal main    
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal main    
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal main    
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal main    
#   # ProtonVPN stable release  #   
deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
#   # ProtonVPN stable release  #   
deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu focal main   
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu focal main     
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu focal main   
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main     
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main     
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/   
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/   
# Tailscale packages for ubuntu focal   
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tailscale-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu focal main   
# Tailscale packages for ubuntu focal   
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tailscale-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/ubuntu focal main   
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main  
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main  
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main  
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###   
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.  
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```

I have tried things like:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources
```

I have tried purging. I have tried installing the missing dependencies that are mentioned, but it fails because I have "held broken packages" e.g.:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wine32:i386 :
> Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be
> installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.

I have tried to list the "broken dependencies" with `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` (https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/800252) which returns nothing.

I have tried purging and starting either method over again:

```
sudo apt remove --purge winehq-stable wine-stable wine1.8 wine-mono wine-gecko wine32:i386
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Nothing has helped. Finally I tried aptitude which suggested the following solution:

```
"sudo aptitude install winehq-stable
(edited out due to character limit and request for other long output)"
```

Would this be safe to do? Will it lead to problems elsewhere? (And will it even resolve my issue?)

Comment: I had to replace "but it is not going to be installed" to "b" in the last output because otherwise the question would exceed the character limit.

Comment: Are you installing the version from the Ubuntu repos?  If not, undo all you have done and install that version.

Comment: @Organic, I gave the exact commands I used to install above. So you can see the answer. I think with "the version from the Ubuntu repos" you mean the one you get with apt-get so the answer is yes. I also tried the method recommended by winehq (with the installer for 20.04).

Comment: Let's see. Please add the output of `apt policy wine32` to your question. I'm pretty sure you're using some ppa because the Ubuntu repos don't have all those versions.

Comment: Right now it's "wine32:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive focal/universe i386 Packages"
I think I ran it before and it was a longer list but at some time I was purging and starting over which I guess is why there is less now.

Comment: Please put the output in the question, as requested. I'm not familiar with that kind of repo but that is the proper version of the package for 20.04 . Have you tried `sudo apt install wine` since you did all the purging and starting over? If so, it would be best to update your question with the current output. It seems at some point you added sources from winehq, be sure to remove all of them. You must remove the *sources* not just the packages from them. `winehq-stable` does not exist in the standard Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Indeed that install now works. I realize now I asked the wrong question. I need wine32. (Or rather rushing to the end of the XY question, I need pdf viewer with JavaScript support. To that end I installed PlayOnLinux which in turns hangs when installing Acrobat Reader and gives the error: "it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"). Hence I tried to install wine32 and failed. So I need to edit the question that the issue is with wine32 and not normal wine.

Comment: Installing wine32 may work also now that you have removed the winehq source. But yeah, if it doesn't, consider updating the question to show the current situation.

Comment: I immediately tried after installing wine but it does not:
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. (...)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: Just to get a definitive answer: **Did you remove the winehq source that you added with this command `sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources`** If you don't remove this source, you will have dependency problems.

Comment: Did the `apt policy wine32` output I showed not show it was removed? Otherwise how would I check? How would I remove it?

(Also from what I read elsewhere the winehq  download is supposed to be the more reliable way no?)

Comment: OK, I take it you did not remove the source. That is the cause of your problems. Go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and if there are any files in there that contain lines referring to wine, remove those files. Then run `sudo apt update` and try installing wine32 again.

Comment: There was indeed one file with winehq in the name. I deleted it. Ran `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install wine32` it gave the same error as before.

Comment: *sigh* it would have been so much easier if you had just installed the repo version to begin with. What is the output of apt policy libwine:i386?

Comment: I mean the first thing I tried was:
"sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine32"

as recommended elsewhere. That is the "repo version" right? I only tried winehq after this had failed and I found the recommendation to do it that way.

"apt policy libwine:i386
libwine:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/linux/distributions/Ubuntu/archive focal/universe i386 Packages
"

Comment: Wasn't the actual first thing you tried to do was install playonlinux?

Comment: Well yes that is true. (I meant I tried sudo apt install wine32 before getting it from winehq.)

Comment: What instructions did you follow to install playonlinux?

Comment: Just `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`. That ran without any errors.

Comment: OK, I have a 20.04 virtual machine. I'm going to go away for a bit and try what you did. Will report back.

Comment: When I did `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` on my plain vanilla 20.04 virtual machine **it installed wine and wine32 as part of the playonlinux installation**, and I was able to successfully install Acrobat Reader through playonlinux. That means I have no idea what is wrong with your system. I am sorry, I do not even know where to begin troubleshooting this. I'm sorry I wasted your time. https://i.imgur.com/O3Mgf9M.png

Comment: @OrganicMarble, no problem, thanks for trying!

Comment: Based on what I saw, the actual problem you had a failure of playonlinux to install its dependencies correctly. I agree that your question is not a duplicate and have voted to reopen it.